# Lucene Numeric Range Query Returning No Results / Unexpected Results

Tags: lucene.net

I'm using Lucene .NET v3 on .NET 4.5. I'm not sure why I'm getting incorrect results in my query. Here's a simple test app:

```
static class Program
{
    static Document MakeDocument(String rcaName, int statusCode)
    {
        var doc = new Document();

        doc.Add(new Field("RCAName", rcaName, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO));
        doc.Add(new Field("ActionId", Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));

        var status = new NumericField("Status", Field.Store.YES, true);
        status.SetLongValue(statusCode);
        doc.Add(status);

        return doc;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var dir = new SimpleFSDirectory(new DirectoryInfo("C:/Sologic/temp/bsindex"));
        // var analyzer = new SologicAnalyzer() { StopWords = StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET };
        var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30);

        using (var writer = new Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter(dir, analyzer, true, Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED))
        {
            writer.AddDocument(MakeDocument("RCA 1", 2));
            writer.AddDocument(MakeDocument("RCA 2", 4));
            writer.AddDocument(MakeDocument("RCA 3", 2));
            writer.AddDocument(MakeDocument("RCA 4", 4));
        }

        var searcher = new Lucene.Net.Search.IndexSearcher(IndexReader.Open(dir, true));
        var query = new Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, "Status", analyzer).Parse("2");

        var hits = searcher.Search(query, 100);

        Console.WriteLine(hits.TotalHits);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

When I open the index with luke, I run the following queries:

```
Status:[2 TO 2] - 0
Status:[4 TO 4] - 0
Status:[0 TO 4] - 4
Status:[0 TO 2] - 4
Status:[0 TO 0] - 0
```

I'm a bit baffled. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

A.) You're setting a long value with an int. I'm guessing this probably is leading to some wonky mishap a level below. Stop doing that.

```
status.SetLongValue(statusCode);
```

becomes

```
status.SetIntValue(statusCode);
```

B.) Don't parse a string to get an int. Basically QueryParser is the wrong choice here. Where you have:

```
var query = new Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, "Status", analyzer).Parse("2");
```

you need

```
var query = NumericRangeQuery.NewIntRange("Status", 4, 4, true, true);
```

So now your problem is solved, but I still get no results in luke. Perhaps it's due to a misunderstanding of the tool itself. Anyhow, happy trails buddy.

Comment: how does status.SetLongValue() become SetIntValue()? statusCode will implicitly be casted to a long.